# Why file gets empty when creating open objects in different modes?

Tags: python, file

I'm writing a simple parser. For now, it reads the whole current dir and open files with 'r' and 'w' permissions for all files that end with ".w". Here's the code for it:

```
import os

wc_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
files = [f for f in os.listdir(wc_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(wc_dir,f))]
comp_files_r = [open(f, 'r') for f in files if f.endswith(".w")]
comp_files_w = [open(f, 'w') for f in files if f.endswith(".w")]
```

As you can see, I have two lists with "open objects" with read and write permissions for all files in the current folder that end with ".w". For now, I have just one file. So, consider the following:

```
print comp_files_r
print comp_files_w
```

Output:

```
[<open file 'app.w', mode 'r' at 0x7effd48274b0>]
[<open file 'app.w', mode 'w' at 0x7effd4827540>]
```

It happens that, when I try to read the 'app.w' file:

```
def parse():

    for f in comp_files_r:
        with f as file:
            data = file.read()

    print repr(data)

parse()
```

I get an astonishing empty string for no reason. I've managed to discover that, all that I save in 'app.w' gets erased when I execute the code with the "w list comprehension". So why is that? I've learned from pain that trying to both read and write a file in "r+" mode can lead to weird results. That's not the situation. I've created different objects from the same file, and **this** is messing with the content of the file itself. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that your issue is that you're opening the file in 'w' mode. When you open a file in 'w' mode, the current file is deleted and replaced with the new file. 'r+' mode is for reading and editing.

I'd be willing to bet that if you read the contents of the files between the lines where you open them for reading and and the line where you open them for writing, you will see the contents of the files as you expect them to be.

Comment: This shows that you are right, and that I am a beginner when dealing with IO. I must use 'a', not 'w' -_-. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was just waiting the necessary 10 min for approval :).